# How to install a Linux distribution on an old android phone?

Tags: linux, keyboard, android, smartphone

I have an old android phone that I would like to install a linux distrobution on. I see many tutorials that involve running a virtual machine on top of android, however this is not what I want. I want to install linux directly on the hardware. I want to run an apache server on it with a distribution like CentOS, so I do not want a fancy desktop environment, but I would like it to have a virtual keyboard to manage it.

Otherwise, how would I connect to it using my USB keyboard? How would I install it onto my phone?

Comment: See https://www.instructables.com/id/Install-GNULinux-on-your-Android-mobile-phone/

Comment: I said on the physical hardware not running in parallel with android

Comment: See the 2nd part of my answer to [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526)

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the tutorials use a virtual machine on top of Android because many of the device drivers required for an Android phone to operate are not available in Linux due to proprietary firmware.

To run on the actual phone hardware, you would need to obtain all of the various device drivers and include them in your custom Linux distribution.  This step is difficult as some of the drivers cannot be legally copied/shared.  Plus, you would need to bypass security measures on the phone hardware that prevent you from installing anything other than Android.

There are a few projects that attempt to do this work for you ([xda-developers](https://www.xda-developers.com) comes to mind), you would need to find them and go through their compatibility databases to look for your phone model.